# fetch tooltip from row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch tool-tip from table row but it returns None.
please look into my code what i tried for this.

```
<tr onmouseover="this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='DodgerBlue';this.originalcolor=this.style.color;this.style.color='White';Tip('<span Style=Color:Red>License: <BR />20-214767 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />20C-214769 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />21-214768 (Validity: 21/05/2022)</span>');" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;this.style.color=this.originalcolor;UnTip();" style="background-color:White;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12px;">
        <td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">AAYUSH PHARMA</td><td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">PUNE-1ST FLOOR, SR.NO.742/A, DINSHOW APARTMENT,,SWAYAM HOSPITAL AND NURSING HOME, BHAWANI PETH</td><td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="center">RH - 3</td><td>swapnil ramakant pawar, BPH, [140514-21/04/2017]</td>
</tr>
```

> **want to fetch text of below tool-tip.**

**Tip('License: 
20-214767 (Validity: 21/05/2022)
20C-214769 (Validity: 21/05/2022)
21-214768 (Validity: 21/05/2022)'**

**Code:**

```
for row in soup.findAll("tr")[1:]:
    licence = row.find("span",{"Style":"Color:Red"})
    print(licence)
```

Comment: `'span'` is a js generated tag. You can use `selenium` or `re`

Comment: I have static html, so why i need selenium ? you can find Tip attribute in my html, it is not dynamic it is static.

Comment: Because `'span'` is generated by js when `onmouseover` event occurs.

Comment: it is not js generated, as i said its a static html page. i have above html code and i wanted to fetch Tip attribute that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got Required output

```
for row in soup.findAll("tr")[1:]:
    attr = row.get('onmouseover')
    Attrsoup = BeautifulSoup(attr,   'html.parser')
    print(Attrsoup.span.text)
```